# Send person to certain website depending on text box space count

Tags: javascript, html

I wanting to make an HTML app that sends you to a certain website depending on the number of spaces in a text box. Here is what I am thinking:

If there are no spaces, go to **google.com**.

Else, go to **bing.com**.

I found this for getting the word count:

```
Count = myText.trim().replace(/\s+/g, ' ').split(' ').length;
```

What should I do from here? I tried making an if statement but got a plethora of errors. All help is appreciated as I am new to HTML. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see that im posting late...

Try the following, I hope this helps you out :)

```js
function submit(){
// Get input contents
  var content=document.getElementById("wierd").value;
// Get space count
var count=(content.match(/ /g) || []).length;
// Redirect the user
// In this example, we dont actually redirect the user since this is quite annoying.
  if(count===0){// If theres no spaces
    console.log("duckduckgo.com");
  }else{
  if(count===1){// If theres 1 space
    console.log("yandex.com");
  }else{
  if(count===2){// If theres 2 spaces
    console.log("yahoo.com");
  }else{//If not a choice
    console.log("unknown.com");
  }
  }
  }
}
```

```css
/*ALL SO related*/

body{
background:#121212;
font-family:Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
input,button{
padding:4px;
margin:5px;
background:#333333;
border:1px solid grey;
color:white;
outline:none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
<input type="text" id="wierd">

<button onclick="submit();">Fire up useless function</button>

</body>
<script src="script.js"></script>
<html>
```

Comment: This helped me out a lot. I made a few modifications but  
 found this incredibly helpful. :) Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

here is my solution and I didn't use your way of finding word count :

```
// select your text box
let text = document.getElementById('someId').value;

// if there is only 1 element in the array then there is no space and redirect to google if not go to bing
if( text.split(' ').length > 1 ){
  window.location = 'https://www.google.com';
} else {
  window.location = 'https://www.bing.com';
}
```

I am making an array from the text in the input by splitting it using the space
example :

text = 'aaaa aaaa aa' ====> going to be ['aaaa', 'aaaa', 'aa']

if there is more than 1 element then there is 1 space at least and we proceed to the if statement

Answer (score 0):

A way to do it:

```
    function redirect(str) {
      var count = str.trim().replace(/\s+/g, ' ').split(' ').length - 1;
      count == 0 ?
      window.open('https://www.google.com/') :
      window.open('https://www.bing.com/') // :
     // you can add more conditions like  count == 1 ? {direction} : {else direction} 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Even though this is completely weird, and probably useless:

```js
function getSite() {
var lookup = {"":"www.google.com", " ": "www.bing.com"};

 var result = document.getElementById("weirdo").value;
  // window.open(lookup[result]);
  // For demo, commented out and logging instead
  alert(lookup[result]);
}
```

```html
<input id="weirdo" type="text"/>
<button type="button" click="getSite()">
Enter text and click me!
</button>
```